# How to precompile Ruby on Rails website into Production Mode?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, apache, production

I have locally made this website on my local Linux Debian 6 under path `/HOME/ADMIN/WWW/WEBSTUDIO` and I need it to be published on my virtual server.

Is "precompiling" the actual word? I know about the command 'rails server' but that is clearly not the same thing as it makes no alterations on the PUBLIC folder.

I guess I have to first transfer my directory structure to server (has Apache2 and ISPCONFIG3 already) and I have done everything so far as how it is [described here](http://www.mirceagoia.com/downloads/Installation_Ruby-on-Rails_for_Ubuntu-Linux-Mint_www-mirceagoia-com.pdf), but it doesn't tell how to put and precompile your site into Prod Mode.

So what's the procedure? ONLY the basic steps.

Comment: On server terminal, from the root of project, run `RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Really?! That's it??? THANK YOU! I'll try that! Any alterations needed on any files? Like mode=PRODUCTION on some file that I now don't remember.

Comment: No, just run the command http://stackoverflow.com/a/25606016/1047207

Comment: what you asking for is called 'deployment'. There are some automation staff to do that, like ```capistrano```, but you can do everything by yourself.

Comment: Yes, I guess there is, but the thing is that I DON'T KNOW HOW. :) That is the whole problem and I don't know where to get any help except here. There is some kind of a Capistrano template thing on Aptana Studio 3 which I use for editing my website but I have no idea how to use it. :( Hope somebody could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you run `rails server` or `rails s` for short your start the rails server

The `precompilation` isn't for the code, it's for the assets (css,js,fonts, images, etc), rails compiles all `css` and `js` each to a single file to reduce the number of http requests needed to load the site.

Also if you are using `scss`, `less` or any of those files that need processing it would be done during the precompilation, and if any gems contain assets it would be copied to the public folder.

The precompilation command as mentioned in other answers/comments is

```
rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: Hi and thanks for the info! So there will NOT be (for example) an index.html -file under the folder PUBLIC? And is it ultimately ALWAYS compulsory to run the 'rails server' command? So basically I need to do nothing more but run the server and let it be?

Comment: OK, I did just as I wrote above, but now my website is ONLY available at: www.web-studio.fi:3000, that is, I need to define the port number but how can I make my site available directly behind www.web-studio.fi? So one wouldn't have to define the port number 3000? Is my site still in Developement Mode? And if so, how do I change that?

Comment: Ok i checked the site, you seem to be using apache, so you could take a look at the passenger module, https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Apache.html

Comment: THANKS! I will check that out. Above there one comment from somebody about Capistrano and automating deployment with that. Should I learn to use Capistrano or do everything by hand? I really am completely new to this stuff :)

Comment: It would be really useful when you start developing an actual application, and start deploying on production servers, but for a start i would just use git and pull the code on the server.

Comment: I need help for this also... I am completely novice to this and I'm sure that at some point I'm going to shout out loud "AHAAAAAA, THIS IS HOW THIS WORKS!" and I'll put out a complete documentary of the procedure but as for now, I need your guys' help with EVERYTHING.

Comment: I'm using Aptana Studio 3 on my Debian Linux host and it indeed does have some kind of a Capistrano macro available and I started that and it would just show me an error "failed" etc. due to some reason. This is so hard I can't explain it. I'm amazed that there are no at-one-place documentation available anywhere since my environment and situation is so common. So that's why I'll compile some kind of a documentation about this whole subject later, when I get a hold on this matter and learn at least 82,47% of it.

Comment: I haven't really dug deep in capistrano before, so I can't really help you with it's configuration, sorry.

Comment: To my knowledge, Capistrano is an automation tool that makes it possible not to do actions (that you know) by hand, but do it automatically.

Comment: Yea, I've used it before (along side the web interface webistrano), but it was installed and configured by someone else other than me, i haven't really done the installation/configuration cycle by my self before, but I know what it is and what it does.

Comment: OK, thanks for answers. I use Aptana Studio 3 for web editing and it has some kind of Capistrano auto-installer but I couldn't make it work. I really would like to use it but again, don't know how. Nothing I try seems to work... :(

Comment: like I said above I haven't tried to configure capistrano my self before, but i plan to soon, when I do i would share what I've found with you.

Comment: Thank You, Mohammad! That would be great! I can also keep You posted on what I find out and learn about RoR in general + Capistrano etc. If You want You can also mail me to: tommi@rockworksstudio.fi

Answer (score 0):

On server terminal, from the root of the project, run:

```
RAILS_ENV=production rake assets:precompile
```

Comment: OK, I just did that and then ran 'rails server', but now my website is ONLY available at: www.web-studio.fi:3000, that is, I need to define the port number but how can I make my site available directly behind www.web-studio.fi? So one wouldn't have to define the port number 3000? Is my site still in Developement Mode? And if so, how do I change that?

I'll accept the answer as soon as You answer this ;)

Comment: @TommiTiihonen This is related to your server (nginx/apache) settings. After closing this question, you should add another question for it with related details...